# How can I configure a Kafka connector that takes messages from SQS and moves them to a Kafka topic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, spring-kafka

I have a use case where I want to move messages from SQS to a Kafka topic. The framework to be used is SpringBoot. So, whenever I run my code it should start moving the messages. I searched for some articles but there were very few. I am looking for some boilerplate code to start with that follow the best practices and how to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make yourself familiar with [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and its [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) implementation.

To take messages from AWS SQS you would need to use an `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` from a [Spring Integration for AWS](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/) extension. To post records into an Apache Kafka topic you need a `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`  from the [`spring-integration-kafka`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-outbound) module.

Then you wire everything together via an [`IntegrationFlow`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl) bean in your Spring Boot configuration.

Of course you can use [Spring Cloud for AWS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws) and [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) directly.
Choice is yours, but better to follow best practice and start developing really an integration solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) offers multiple ways to ingest data from different sources e.g. [Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi), [Kafka Producer](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi), etc., and we need to be careful while selecting specific components of Kafka by keeping certain things in mind such as retry **mechanism**, **scalability**, etc.

The best solution, in this case, would be to use [Amazon SQS Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-sqs/current/overview.html) to **ingest** data from [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) into [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) `topic` and then write your consumer application to do whatever is necessary with the stream of records of that particular `topic`.